# Where can I find video of Pierre Elliott Trudeau's concession in 1979?

Tags: election, canada, 1970s, television

The Canadian parliamentary elections of May 1979 were a defeat for the Liberals and a victory for the Progressive Conservatives, resulting in Pierre Elliott Trudeau's replacement by Joe Clark as prime minister.

If I am not deluded, Trudeau appeared before supporters after the outcome was clear, and some shouted "Don't give up", which I surmise meant they thought he might be able to form a coalition with some other parties. Then Trudeau said he would go and see the governor general, and that he thought he would be a good leader of the opposition, and the crowd applauded.

But the video is nowhere on the internet, as far as I can tell. Or is it? Can anyone direct me to it or explain why it's not there in an age where seemingly everything is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most relevant portion may be found in this show:

YouTube: [Webster! Full Episode May 23, 1979](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kiXAi_QmZuY) (at ~2 min mark)

Transcript:

> Now. Naturally. Naturally.
> Within two and through at most three days, I will be meeting my colleagues and those who form the cabinet with me, as many of the caucus members as possible and deciding on the future of the government.
> I want to – I wanted to
> I wanted to tell you now very ser… (various?)
> I want to tell you now very seriously. And I am very encouraged, am very encouraged by your feelings, but I, but I think, it is my duty at this time, to recommend to my colleagues, that we hand the government over and that I – that I (uproar in audience, Trudeau makes gesture 'to calm down') that I recommend to the governor-general, that he asks Mr Clark to form a government. Mr Clark … (snippet cuts off)

A related documentary made much later gives a bit more juice for context, but glances over this specific part ([video-link, min 8:04](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Q5HBPqzmhY)).

Comment: It looks as if https://www.cbc.ca/archives/categories/politics/elections/ should have some relevant material, but the site is phenomenally dysfunctional for me…

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why I couldn't find it via the obvious search terms on youtube or on Google videos.

Comment: This stops short of the part where he said he'd be a good leader of the opposition.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, sadly, but as indicated by the transcript as well. Do you have any more luck with eg the cbc.ca archives? (page never completes loading all ressoruces for me, regardless of browser or network settings…)

Comment: I just says "Loading". It hasn't brought me to the point where I can enter search terms.

Comment: At around 1:15 that video makes it clear that the Progressive Conservatives also didn't have a majority, so maybe that's not unrelated to the reasons why Joe Clark only lasted six months.

Comment: I see that in June, I wrote that this stops short of the part where he says he will be a good leader of the opposition, but when I view the video tonight, that is there.

Comment: One should also mention that a more complete version begins at about 19:50 in the linked video and lasts several minutes.